# Android Photoshop actions to export to mdpi hdpi xhdpi xxhdpi and xxxhdpi

Tags: android, photoshop, photoshop-script

I know that there are many questions/posts about this topic, but they all are not up to date.
What's the best way/approach to convert psd to android png resources?
Currently I use: `psd -> export vector -> Android Asset Studio -> pngs`
But seems like it's more like a hack...

What's your approach to handle it. Thanks.

Or maybe it's time to use primarily only vector images?

Comment: Could you explain why that's a hack and what's wrong with that approach if it works?

Comment: it requires 2-steps actions, would like to smiplify it if possible

Answer (score 1):

I can advise you to export your draws as .svg format and import it to your project as a vector. Less complex, less project sizes.

Comment: Hi i have heard that Vector drawable is not supported for launcher icons and we need to use mipmap folders. I would like to know is it fully supported for other options like in the place of normal png drawable? I am developing an app and I wanted to reduce its size, i hope vector drawables are the answers. Any suggestions from your side?